# Split View Controller to set UIScrollView Offset

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

Would it be possible to have a splitview controller that controls the offset of a UIScrollView which is in the detail view.

Basically I have one long image inside a scroll frame in the detail view and I want to be able to jump to parts of the image by using the MastwerViewController table as a "navigation" bar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: It's possible, a split view controller knows who its children are, so it can definitely talk to them. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for setting the content offset of the scroll view programmatically.

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newOffset, 0) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Maybe `[(UIScrollView *)self.masterViewController.view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newOffset, 0) animated:YES]` would be much better.

Comment: @Cyrille why would it be "much better"? This is an example, you're expected to 1. determine which parts can and should be changed 2. sensibly substitute the parts which can change to their actual values.

Comment: Hi Carbonic Acid, maybe I'm too quick to give the full-fledged answer?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies, I will try when I get home tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the offset value of a scrollView according to which part you going to show when you click on master view then you bind those offset value to this method

```
-(void) MoveScrollView:CGPointMake(CGFloat X, CGFloat Y)
{
     [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(CGFloat X, CGFloat Y) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please could you explain which file I would implement this code into, and how I link it to the table view in the MasterViewController.
For example i want a list of 4 "items"
Item 1 - Set's offset to 300px
Item 2 - Set's offset to 600px
Item 3 - Set's offset to 900px etc. 

Thanks :)